# PHP Form Group Results From Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php form that allows the user to add multiple copies of three fields (installed item, description, and quantity). The results of each field are captured in an array.

I am sending the results via an email form. Currently I have it set to the following:

```
$email_body = "Date: $date \n".
   "Installed Items: \n" . implode("\n", $_POST['installed']) . "\n" .
   "Installed Description: \n" . implode("\n", $_POST['installed-description']) . "\n" .
   "Installed Quantity: \n" . implode("\n", $_POST['installed-quantity']) . "\n";
```

It displays like this in the email:

Installed Items:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Installed Description:

```
Description 1
Description 2
Description 3
```

Installed Quantity:

```
Quantity 1
Quantity 2
Quantity 3
```

I would like for it to display as follows:

```
Item 1
Description 1
Quantity 1

Item 2
Description 2
Quantity 2

etc...
```

Any help would be appreciated (and, I'm pretty new to PHP so pardon the noob-ness of this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would recommend to use a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < COUNT($_POST['installed']);$i++)
{
   $msg .= 'Item '.$i.'\n';
   $msg .=  $_POST['installed'][$i].'\n';
   $msg .=  $_POST['installed-description'][$i].'\n';
   $msg .=  $_POST['installed-quantity'][$i].'\n';
   $msg .= '\n'; //extra space between the items
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ofir-baruch! This looks like exactly what I was looking for. However, I'm getting a syntax error when I drop it into the $email_body section of my code.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error in my browser and Dreamweaver (i know, i know) is giving me a general message that I have a syntax error on the first line.

Comment: `$email_body = "Date: $date \n". 
   
   for($i = 0; $i < COUNT($_POST['installed']);$i++)
  {
     $msg .= 'Item '.$i.'\n';
     $msg .=  $_POST['installed'][$i].'\n';
     $msg .=  $_POST['installed-description'][$i].'\n';
     $msg .=  $_POST['installed-quantity'][$i].'\n';
     $msg .= '\n'; //extra space between the items
  }
     
  $to = "chuck@374designs.com";`

Comment: sorry...don't know how to paste that so it looks nice.

Comment: You forgot semicolon in this part:`$email_body = "Date: $date \n".`
Instead of this one , write: `$email_body = "Date: $date \n";`

Comment: It's not throwing errors, but now it's not sending any of the form info.

Comment: My friends , be aware to the difference between my code and yours.
I used `$msg` and you're using another variable, just change the `$msg` variable to `$email_body` and it will work.

Comment: It shows this when I drop in that code at the end:
Array ( [date] => [location] => [job-number] => [super] => [foreman] => [weather] => [traffic] => [over-utilities] => [under-utilities] => [other-hazards] => [other-ppe] => [description] => [installed] => Array ( [0] => test1 ) [installed-description] => Array ( [0] => desc 1 ) [installed-quantity] => Array ( [0] => quan 1 ) )

Comment: Most of those items are other variables i have set up in another part of the email form php file.

Comment: I figured it out. It was in the way I was constructing the actual message. Thank you so much for your help!